# anti cloning hard disk

Tags: windows, linux, boot

I'm trying to create an "anti-cloning" system. I'd like to know if there's a way to check a unique label on the hard disk, during the boot phase, in order to avoid the machine to continue booting if the hard disk was cloned.

I've googled a lot, but nothing interesting came out...

Since I have two hard disks, the first one with Windows 10, and the other one with Ubuntu:

1. Do I need two different solutions, or should I create a Grub script and use it for both?
2. What kind of unique ID should I check?
3. How and where should I store that ID in order to avoid as much as possible a change by someone else?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I'm editing my question, because I think it has been a little misinterpreted.

My main goal is prevention. For example, I have a secure system but it's still "virgin" (first time configuration for example) and some dedicated software/data is saved inside. How can I prevent that someone else clone my system and use it for it's own purposes?

That's why I was thinking about a boot script

Comment: Just curious because that's a pretty unique concept: what is it supposed to protect?

Comment: With Windows 10, you can consider the best half of your disk already cloned by Microsoft <s>

Comment: Start a sentence with the words: "I want to protect..." and then add what you want to protect (**not** what you want to protect **from**).

Comment: @techraf I want to protect the entire system... The configuration I've made for the OS for example, or the software I've developed that is inside etc...

Comment: Essentially, it's a DRM problem, rather than a security problem.  It has all the usual issues with DRM - when you supply the system to a customer, you also have to supply the "keys" (whatever they are on your system) so that the user can use it.  You can use a custom script to check that the machine is genuine.  But the customer has the script, and can edit it to remove the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. At least, if you allow attackers physical access to your machine, you've lost the battle already.

- Use full disk encryption.
- Keep attackers away from your machine.

The only kind of adversaries who'd clone your disk instead of stealing it or installing a rootkit/ keylogger/ whatever nastiness is on the menu today are law enforcement, and they won't *boot* your disk but rather study it in a clean environment.

If you rely on encryption, they will try to learn the password and then proceed to decrypt the contents of the disk instead of running anything from it (i.e. bootloader code will not be executed). Even if they boot your 'modified' loader from the disk, they will see that the OS doesn't load and will bypass your 'custom routine' after the first time using a pristine copy.

P.S. There are incompetent LE officers a-plenty, but they tend to work in departments unrelated to computer forensics.

Comment: What message do you try to convey in your third paragraph?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand very much the answer at all... Are you saying that encryption is the only solution? Shouldn't I add both systems?

Comment: @IlGala - 1. Use full-disk encryption. 2. Keep attackers away from your system when it is powered on or has been recently shut down.

Comment: Your third paragraph actually leaves impression that encryption is useless (syntax: if you do it, they will do something else and proceed).

Comment: @techraf - FDE is useful, but there are ways around it: acoustic keyloggers, shoulder surfing/cameras, "rubber hose cryptanalysis". A determined adversary with enough money **can** learn your password.

Comment: I've edited my question... I think it has been a little misinterpreted... I hope these other details may be usefull

Comment: @IlGala - the use case is absolutely unclear. If a person has access to your computer, s/he can bloody well steal it.

Comment: @DeerHunter I'm sorry, I'm trying to be as much clear as possible. The use case may be: I want to replicate my system, for example, into a customer machine, with a good FDE, dedicated software etc...
My customer cheats me and tries to sell my system by his own, replicating it into another hard disk. Let me clarify that my question is most of all "theory" and I'm trying to create something that can be secure from the first boot.

Comment: @IlGala - this is a 'mission impossible' scenario. If you give the machine to your customer, say 'Good bye' to your intellectual property unless you want to hire a lawyer and enforce your rights. There is no technical solution for that.

Comment: I think fetching the keys from a TPM chip is hard for most adversaries.